# Running Ping through exec function in Android

Tags: java, android, ping, netcat

Im trying to get an ARM binary of netcat running on my droid. Its already contained in the data/local/tmp folder on the device. The netcat commands also work via adb shell.

However, im trying to execute commands from code, netcat wasnt working so I decided to start with a basic command like ping. My code below is an attempt to ping my laptop from the phone.

Again this worked from adb shell but doesnt seem to work from the code. I captured in wireshark and no packet came from the phone when the code was ran.

Can anyone tell me why the ping is not working? Once I fix that part I can move onto other commands.

Also, I have tried the .waitFor command to wait for the command to run but this gives an error in eclipse.

Thanks

```
package com.maurice.netcat;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NetcatActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Netcat");
    setContentView(text);

    try
    {
        String ping = "system/bin/ping -c 1 192.168.0.13";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ping);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Netcat Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }


    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Executing Netcat");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Exception Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have followed lots of tutorials online for this but it simply doesnt seem to work for me. If anyone has any suggestions I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you mean `/system/bin/ping` not `system/bin/ping`. That probably accounts for the problem.

Second, you will need to make sure that your application process has all the permissions required by `ping`, since those permissions are inherited by any executables you launch. So you'll definitely need `android.permission.INTERNET` and it seems possible that `ping` might need some additional lower-level permissions in order to send the ICMP packets it needs (I'm not sure).

A useful tip to make sure your application has the right permissions: do `run-as com.myapplication.packagename.here ping -c 1 192.168.0.13`, from an `adb` shell. That will run the ping command with the same sort of security context as your app, so you'll see if there are permission problems.

Finally, it's generally frowned upon to launch external executables, and in theory the Android framework reserves the right to exterminate any such executables it discovers. In practice it doesn't do that right now.